# Where is a mysql volume db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data stored?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get my head around docker and confused how the volumes work.

On the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) there's a bit of code similar to the `docker-compose.yml` file I'm working with.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - overlay
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      endpoint_mode: vip

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
       - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    networks:
       - overlay
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  overlay:
```

I'm confused as to what the `db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data` refers to and where docker is actually storing the database data, especially as `/var/lib/mysql` doesn't exist as a directory on the host.

Comment: Docker volumes are persisted on the host in /var/lib/docker/volumes generally using the format $COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME_$VOLUME_NAME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this line

```
volumes:
   - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

basically mounts the volume `db-data` from host into `/var/lib/mysql/data` in the container.

If `db-data` doesn't exist Docker will create one for you in Host.

You can read more [here.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 1):

This is no bin-mount. The docker-compose file creates a volume named db-data that is not linked to any path (by the last entry "db-data: ") and is taken care of by docker internally (will probably turn up inside /var/lib/docker or similar, but this wouldn't matter because you usually use this if you don't care where the data is put, you just want persistence).

The db-data volume that is administered by docker on the host machine is then linked to the path /var/lib/mysql/data in the container, so anything within this path in the container will be persistent for as long as the volume isn't deleted on the host.